# I have lost the ability to add custom scripts to my QGis processing toolbox

Tags: qgis

I tried to load a new script to my processing toolbox panel and it didn't work.  The screen flashed a few times and I lost the icon and existing scripts that were available.

This is the error that I get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 128, in loadAlgorithms
    alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 67, in loadAlgorithm
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "", line 851, in exec_module
  File "", line 988, in get_code
  File "", line 918, in source_to_code
  File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\potat\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\ProcessPipes.py", line 17
    class (QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.5-Firenze Firenze, 50adba36f2 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/potat/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/potat/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\grass\grass82\etc\python
C:\Users\potat\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.5\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.5\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/potat/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\potat\AppData\Local\Temp\tuflow_refh2z7brzz0c
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.1\debug-eggs
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.1\debug-eggs
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\debug-eggs
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev
E:/A-Team Dropbox/Afflux Consulting Team Folder/550-01_ManninghamFlood/Hydraulics/Ruffey
```

I am able to load the new script (and previous) on a different machine running the same version of QGis (3.28) so I don't think it is an issue with the script (especially as the ones that loaded previously don't load anymore and haven't been changed).
I have unistalled and reinstalled QGis which didn't make a difference.
I also have an earlier vesrion installed (3.22) and am experiencing the same issues.